# Mail Merge Document ..! group by and Save in one PDF format as per the Employee Name Like SMS Thread

Tags: excel, vba, mailmerge

Please help to any VBA code to save data Form as a PDF in one thread as per the EMP id Eg: Having 4 Accounts so Form showing in one PDF like Thread.
I m Using VBA code :

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'


Sheets("Retailer Dialogue-All retailers").Select
  Range("g5").Select
Dim r As Range
For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("e2")


  
   
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & i).Copy
   
   

    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & i), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next
End Sub
```

It saves individually PDF in the folder Required Employee wise PDF with Grouping in one

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Create a new temporary workbook, copy the individual sheets into it and then export it as PDF.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Macro2()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsDump As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, key
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long

    ' create list of empids
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDump = wb.Sheets("Dump")
    With wsDump
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, "K"))
            If Len(key) > 0 Then
               dict(key) = 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox dict.Count & " Employees" & vbCrLf _
           & Join(dict.keys, vbCrLf), vbInformation

    ' createPDFs for each empid
    For Each key In dict.keys
        Call Macro1(CStr(key))
    Next
    ' create combined
    Call Macro1("")

End Sub

Sub Macro1(empid As String)
       
    Const PDF_FILENAME = "AllSheets.pdf"
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbPDF As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsForm As Worksheet, wsDump As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, pdfname As String

    ' config
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDump = wb.Sheets("Dump")
    Set wsForm = wb.Sheets("Retailer Dialogue-All retailers")
    
    ' create a new workbook and add sheets to it
    Set wbPDF = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    n = wbPDF.Sheets.Count
    For i = 2 To ws.Range("E2").Value2
        ' filter on empid or all if ""
        If empid = "" Or wsDump.Cells(i, "K") = empid Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("G5")
            wsForm.Copy after:=wbPDF.Sheets(n)
            n = n + 1
            wbPDF.Sheets(n).Name = i & "_" & ws.Range("C" & i).Value2
        End If
    Next

    ' delete blank sheet1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbPDF.Sheets(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    If empid = "" Then
        pdfname = PDF_FILENAME
    Else
        pdfname = empid & ".pdf"
    End If
    
    ' export to pdf and close not saved
    wbPDF.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfname, _
         Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
         IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    wbPDF.Close False

    MsgBox "PDF created " & pdfname, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou so much .. For helping but got some error after using mentioned script here we attached the sample file for reference..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A34_ylIhsk65i5Bsb2TCNAZ3mQpdhh2i/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Sir Getting Error on         ws.Range("C" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("G5")
        wsForm.Copy after:=wbPDF.Sheets(wbPDF.Sheets.Count)
        wbPDF.Sheets(i).Name = ws.Range("C" & i).Value2

Comment: Sample File is pasted on Drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A34_ylIhsk65i5Bsb2TCNAZ3mQpdhh2i/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: ws.Range("C" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("G5") Getting error 1004

Comment: @Shaf Is `Sheets("Retailer Dialogue-All retailers")` protected ? Is `G5` part of merged cells ? Does the code you posted work OK ?

Comment: Thankyou So Much Sir Its Working fine ,its Great help ....!

Comment: Sir May We add one more command for save excel as per Emp_id wise A.pdf,  
 bCPdf ,  C.pdf

Comment: @Shaf Which excel ? do you mean change the pdf filename from AllSheets.pdf to something like A_B_C_D.pdf where A,B.C,D are the values in column C.

Comment: Yes, Sir Means i like to share Individually Emp_id Wise PDF to Employees, Eg: Employee.A having 25 Records so I have to send 25 Records in one PDf  to A,Next same for B

Comment: @Shaf Which column is Emp_Id ? I can't access your sample, can you make it public ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A34_ylIhsk65i5Bsb2TCNAZ3mQpdhh2i/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Sir Shared On thread..

Comment: @Shaf see update. Run macro2 which will create individual pdfs as well as a combined one.

Comment: Thankyou Sir It's Working fine ...Issue facing in Emp Wise it publishes data 1 to 48 in 1 to 50 only and from 49th onwards its taking data for the next emp .Please look if any changes happen in code once .

Comment: @Shaf The Emp_id is in col K on the Dump sheet whereas the pdf values are on Sheet1 so check rows 49 onwards align for those 2 sheets.

Comment: Thankyou Sir ..Its Working Fine ....thankyou for Tremendous support..